# SSL certificate for a Gitlab server on the local network

Tags: ubuntu, https, gitlab, ssl-certificate

I want to deploy Gilab on a local network on an Ubuntu server. Unfortunately, access via https does not work. The domain name of my gitlab server is gitlab.mydoimain.com. It is only valid on the local network.

The `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` command displays the following error message:

```
letsencrypt_certificate[gitlab.mydomain.de] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 6 had an error: RuntimeError: acme_certificate[staging] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 43) had an error: RuntimeError: ruby_block[create certificate for gitlab.mydomain.de (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 110) had an error: Runtime: [gitlab.mydomain.de] Validation failed, unable to request certificate, Errors: [{url:https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/4261410484/v_r_Dw, status: invalid, error:{"type"=>urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized", "detail"=>"81.14.185.232: Invalid response from http://gitlab.mydomain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/MoBKtz...:502", "status"=> 403})
```

**What have I tried so far?**
I deleted all files in /etc/gitlab/ssl/ and created a new private key and my own new certificate in it.

gitlab.mydomain.key
gitlab.mydomain.csr
However, that doesn't work either.